# Visual Studio Code include single file on excluded path

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have configured Visual Studio Code (VCS) to exclude the *imported* directory and all code under it using:

```
    "files.exclude": {
    "**/imported": true
    }
```

This *imported* folder is very large, containing many large code bases. It is excluded for performance reasons.

However I want to still include some imported library interface files so they can be source indexed.

For example, I want to still include *imported/library-a/library-a-interface.h* to simplify development using these interfaces (structure fields shown in the editor, etc).

Is this possible? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

As of VS Code 1.15, we don't have a good story for this. We are tracking the issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/869)

Comment: Ah that's unfortunate, no workarounds without manually encoding the entire directory scope?

Comment: None that I am aware of