# How to ignore single file #include warning in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

I've recently switched to Visual Studio Code as IDE for a more complex Arduino project.

In order to avoid "cannot open source file" warnings related to `#include` statements for builtin Arduino libraries, I already added the Arduino directory to IntelliSence `includePath` setting.

Unfortunately, two external libraries do contain an `#include` for older Arduino versions:

```
#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
extern "C" {
#include "WConstants.h" // <-- this is the first
}
#endif
```

and

```
#if ARDUINO >= 100
#include <Arduino.h>
#else
#include "WProgram.h" // <-- this is the second
#include "pins_arduino.h" // <-- this one was found in Arduino dir
#endif
```

As this files is no longer part of the Arduino environment, I get a warning.

**Question**: How do I exclude this warnings regarding `WConstants.h` and `WProgram.h` from Visual Studio Code's IntelliSense without deactivating any other include warnings?

I am not sure whether this is related to [Visual Studio Code include single file on excluded path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45574859/visual-studio-code-include-single-file-on-excluded-path) .

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234438/vs-code-giving-header-errors-for-arduino-missing-official-header) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, it does not. The linked issue addresses only correct include paths, which I already did. The issue I have is that the mentioned libraries do not exist on my PC, as they are not included in recent Arduino IDE and included in the libraries for backwards compatibility, only.  Hence, I'd like to ignore only those specific include warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a [post in Arduino forum](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/cannot-open-source-file-wprogram-h-in-vscode), I found a solution:

The Arduino IDE adds a macro with it's version. So adding `ARDUINO=10813` in the vscode config renders the include of `WProgram.h` and `WConstants.h` inactive, hence no more include warnings.

Similar thing can be achieved for `Serial` library by adding `USBCON`.

So vscode config should look like:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {

            ...

            "defines": [
                "USBCON",
                "ARDUINO=10813"
            ],

            ...

        }
    ],

}
```